# Deserialization of Blob not working

Tags: java, postgresql, deserialization, blob

A `List<List<String>>` is persisted as a `byte[]` (Blob) in a postgres-db. However, the deserialization does not work. No exception is thrown but the size of the list always is zero.

The `List<List<String>>` is converted into a `byte[]` and then set into the MyBlobEntity before persisting. Afterwards the entity is retrieved from the db and the `byte[]` converted back into a `List<List<String>>`. I tested the converter in a unit test by converting from List to byte-array and back to a List. That seems to be working fine.

Entity

```
@Entity(name = "MyBlobEntity")
@Table(name = "t_my_blob")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BlobIdGenerator", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "sq_blob_id")
public class MyBlobEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "blob_id", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BlobIdGenerator")
  private Long internalId;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String filename;

  @Lob
  @Basic
  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")
  private byte[] data;

  public Long getInternalId() {
    return internalId;
  }

  public void setInternalId(final Long internalId) {
    this.internalId = internalId;
  }

  public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
  }

  public void setFilename(final String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
  }

  public byte[] getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(final byte[] data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Converter

```
public class MyBlobConverter {

  public byte[] convert(final List<List<String>> lines) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
      final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
      oos.writeObject(lines);
      oos.flush();
      data = bos.toByteArray();
      oos.close();
      bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
  }

  public List<List<String>> convert(final byte[] data) {
    final ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    List<List<String>> lines = null;
    try {
      final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
      lines = (List<List<String>>) ois.readObject();
      ois.close();
      bis.close();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
  }

}
```

The table is created with

```
create table t_my_blob(
    blob_id numeric(38) NOT NULL,
    filename varchar(255) not NULL,
    data bytea not null
);
```

Comment: There is no type `BLOB` in Postgres. What is the real data type of that column?

Comment: I updated the post with the create-statement. It is a bytea type.

Comment: In the meantime I am using jdbc calls which works but still looking forward to suggestions/hints/solutions.